# Xcode Bots:: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 65

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode-server, xcode-scheme

My integration succeeded but archive fails every-time with following warning mentioned below -:

```
**Warning: Build Service Error:** Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 65.  
**Warning: Build Service Error:** Skipping exporting from archive because creating the archive failed.
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case the code signing was set to automatic. When I change it to an distribution certificate it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel..I did try this before it didn't work but now it works....May be previously I was trying before copying my provisioning profiles to /Library/Developer/Xcode Server/ProvisioningProfiles..So sorry as I don't have too much reputation (i.e. 15 is required) I can't vote up for you..but whenever I will have I ll do it for you..Cheers!!!

Comment: What I have noticed in the build log(/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/0bf59b5e7af4ba98e99d13d1a80f2b28 Bot/1/build.log), Command /usr/bin/codesign trying to sign my app with OS X Developer certificate which is created by Xcode server (I guess) and archive is getting failed because I don't have private key for that..!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue after updating to the Server beta. I was able to fix it by [adding my team to the Xcode server settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/adopt_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH3-SW16).

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of certificate. Try to check if you have the certificate on your machine corresponding to the build you want to make.