# Xcode Server Integration Error

Tags: ios, xcode9, xcode-server

I have enabled Xcode server in Xcode 9. I am able to create a BOT but when I am trying to integrate, getting below error

```
Assertion: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 65.
```

I have added distribution certificate & provisioning profile but still facing the same issue.

I have followed below links but no success

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794034/xcode-bots-creating-archive-failed-xcodebuild-exited-with-status-65)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091625/xcode-server-bot-integration-fails-to-export-archive-with-assertion-fail-export)
[Link3](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25980)

Please help how to resolve this issue. Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Looking through the 'raw build log' on the integration, the very end of the log should have the reason. I am using automatic code signing and I'm getting the report: "Code Signing Error: You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support." It looks as if automatic code signing between the project and the server has issues right now.